# How do I add tailwindcss utility classes to Quill's text align dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, quill, react-quill

I am using [Tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) in my project, [which uses](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-align) `text-left`, `text-center`, `text-right`, and `text-justify` to align text.

[Quill](https://quilljs.com), however, adds `ql-align-left`, `ql-align-center`, `ql-align-right`, and `ql-align-justy` to align text.

How do I configure Quill (or [react-quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill)) to use or add Tailwindcss's utility classes instead of Quill's css classes?

My end goal is to easily combine Tailwindcss and Quill, so alternative routes to that end goal are also welcome.

I've looked at this [custom formats section](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#custom-formats) already, but I couldn't find a way to extend or create a dropdown-ish sort of toolbar item that adds the correct classes.

I did however succeed in adding the classes as an Inline Blot:

```
import { Quill } from "react-quill";

class AlignRight extends Inline {}

AlignRight.blotName = 'align-right';
AlignRight.className = 'text-right';
AlignRight.tagName = 'div';
AlignRight.keyName = 'align';
```

However, this adds the classes like it would apply `bold` and `italic`. This made it possible to apply both `text-right` and `text-center` at the same time:

```html
<div class="text-right">
  <div class="text-center">
    this text has alignment conflicts
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously this is not what I want. As with the already existing alignment toolbar item, selecting a new text alignment should turn off the previous alignment.

Furthermore, based on [these docs](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#attributors), I was also expecting to be able to import a class attributor and do something like this:

```
let Align = Quill.import('attributors/class/align');

class AlignRight extends Align {}
```

But the imported `Align` is an object and not a class I can extend.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this myself , not a very clean solution by i wrote a function that read the value from quill editor when i click submit and then directly tweak the String content before submiting it to the database , like that (handlecontentChange will run after onChange of Quill):

```js
const handleContentChange = () => {
    const v = value.replace(/<h1/g, '<h1 class="your-custom-tailwind-classes"');
    setValue(v);
};
```

```html
<ReactQuill
value={value}
onChange={setValue}
/>
```